# Conditional format a cell with a graduated colour when a range of other cells are completed with text

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to conditionally format a cell with a graduated colour (traffic light: green/ amber/ red), when a range of other cells are completed with text within google sheets.

In other words, 4 cells (B3:B6) will be completed with information so when no cells or 1 cell contains text, then my target cell (B2) will show green. When 2 or 3 cells are completed then B2 will show amber and when all 4 cells are completed then B2 will show red.

I hope this makes sense & can help.

Answer (score 1):

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093403

use the custom formula option. enter `=COUNTBLANK(B3:B6) = 0` for your red condition.

`=AND(COUNTBLANK(B3:B6) > 0, COUNTBLANK(B3:B6) < 3)` for your amber condition

`=COUNTBLANK(B3:B6) > 3` for the green condition